# Silverlight TextBox switch text alignment in runtime

Tags: .net, silverlight, web, localization

I have a normal standard TextBox in Silverlight.

**As a user**, I want to switch the text alignment in **runtime** (the browser) from left to right and the other way around- a modest request I think.

The Ctrl + Shift keys don't work. They do however work for any other Windows application.

What's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want a clear answer ask a clear question: "What's going on here?" is a bit too unspecific. How about "How do I set up my TextBox to behave that way?".

Answer (score 0):

To me your question is not fully clear. But If you want to change allignment of textbox at runtime. This'd work fine:

```
myTextBox.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center; // or whatever you want
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textalignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: The problem is in runtime like I mentioned.

Comment: @alex: Changing the `TextAlignment` property is supported at runtime. The Silverlight framework allows for that.